# org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType not converting value in JPASQLQuery

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

In my model, I declare this NumericBooleanType attribute:

```
@Column(name = "ST_ATIVO", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private Boolean ativo;
```

Then, in antother class, I am trying to do the following query:

```
List<Long> test = this.sqlQueryFactory.query()
            .select(equipe.id)
            .from(equipe)
            .where(equipe.ativo.isTrue())
            .fetch();
```

However, I got this error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = boolean
```

Shoudn't a NumericBooleanType boolean attribute in the query be converted to int by hibernate?

Comment: Could you please show ddl for the `ST_ATIVO` column

Comment: tb_table  | st_ativo    | integer

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what query api do you use. Assuming that you use [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) you can try to correct your query in this way:

```java
JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
List<Long> test = queryFactory.query()
   .select(equipe.id)
   .from(equipe)
   .where(equipe.ativo.eq(true))
   .fetch();
```